# Oreo not calling onLocationChanged method from Schedule Job

Tags: android, performance, android-location, android-8.0-oreo, android-jobscheduler

I am calling `location service` from a `JobSchedular` to make it work even when the app is in background.

This is how i schedule my `LocationService`

```
JobInfo jobInfo;
JobScheduler jobScheduler;

ComponentName componentName= new ComponentName(this, LocationUpdateService.class);
JobInfo.Builder builder= new JobInfo.Builder(11, componentName);

builder.setPeriodic(900000);
builder.setRequiredNetworkType(JobInfo.NETWORK_TYPE_ANY);
builder.setPersisted(true);

jobInfo= builder.build();
jobScheduler= (JobScheduler) getSystemService(JOB_SCHEDULER_SERVICE);


jobScheduler.schedule(jobInfo);
```

Now It calls the `LocationUpdateService`, and executes `onCreate()` and `onStartJob` methods but does not execute `onLocationChanged()` in `oreo`. This works perfectly fine on `Nougat` and `lollipop` devices

All of the logic of either to send user location to service or not is in `onLocationChanged()`, and if i put the logic in `onStartJob()`, i am unable to get user's `lat/lng`.

```
public class LocationUpdateService extends JobService implements
        LocationListener,
        GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
        GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,
        IServiceResponse {

  @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        Log.i(TAG, "onCreateCalled: ");
        if (isGooglePlayServicesAvailable()) {

            mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                    .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                    .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                    .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                    .build();

            mGoogleApiClient.connect();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onStartJob(JobParameters params) {

        Log.i(TAG, "onStartCommand: ");
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onStopJob(JobParameters params) {
        Log.d("JobStopped", "JobStopped");
        return true;
    }


    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

    }
```

I also tried this to get user's `lat/lng` in `onStartJob`, but it returned me (0,0) `lat/lng`

```
Location location= new Location("");
location.getLongitude()
```

I am using `play-services` version `11.0.4`

Comment: https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background-location-limits